# How to join two dataframes using dplyr in order to agregate values of the same column?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, tibble

Is there a simple and elegant way to left join (with dplyr) a "b" table in an "a" table when both contains the same column, but the first has NA's and the second table has the missing values? Here folows an example:

```R
# Tables A and B
a <- tibble(
  "ID" = c(1,2,3),
  "x" = c(NA,5, NA)
)

b <- tibble(
  "ID" = c(1,3),
  "x" = c(7, 4)
)

# Table I want as result
c <- tibble(
  "ID" = c(1,2,3),
  "x" = c(7,5,4)
)
```

Comment: would `filter(a, complete.cases(a)) %>% full_join(b)` work?

Comment: `na.omit(rbind(a,b))`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `coalesce` function in the `dplyr` package to match together a complete vector from missing pieces. This is inspired by the sql COALESCE function.

```
left_join(a,b, by='ID') %>%
  mutate(col = coalesce(x.x, x.y)) %>%
  select(ID, col)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID   col
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     7
2     2     5
3     3     4
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that I need to type the name of the columns (example: "x.x, x.y ..."). But I used this answer because doing this way I do not lose rows that does not match (in real case I have this situation, even that I did not show in the example of my question). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Joining and then removing rows with an `NA` should do it. If an `ID` has non-`NA` values of `x` in both tables, then this code will have 2 rows for that `ID`, but that is probably the behavior you'd want

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(a,b, by = c('ID', 'x')) %>%
    na.omit()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     5
2     1     7
3     3     4
```